# Cordova receive event in android app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to Cordova and looking on how to capture events fired from JS in my Android app while using Cordova web view.

I have this class which implements CordovaInterface and have this function (that I guess receive events):

```
@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin cordovaPlugin)
{}
```

I successfully implemented the web view with a JS game embedded in it.
Say I receive events in that interface how do I differentiate events so I will handle each appropriately?

Looking for some code example or references which will help me get started

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml. You can found this file in res > xml folder.

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.Phonegap.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Then you need to implement plugin by using Java- code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally we calling a plugin from javascript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/10/androidios-adding-native-functionality-to-hybrid-application-with-apache-cordova-plugin/